# Google or-tools: Export and Load a GLOP linear solver if solution and model is known

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm new to Google or-tools and facing the below problem. I'm creating a linear solver like this -

```
solver = pywraplp.Solver('my_solver', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
# Added 70K variables and 180K constraints in 1.5 hrs
status = solver.Solve()
if status = pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
 # It took 10 min to output an optimal solution
else:
 # ...

model = solver.ExportModelToProto()
solution = solver.FillSolutionResponseProto()
model_str = text_format.MessageToString(model)
solution_str = text_format.MessageToString(solution)
# WRITE model_str & solution_str to File using Pickle
```

The problem statement is to be able to reuse this pre-initialised solver , add new variables / constraints (if needed) and Solve() again.

```
# Unpickle and READ model_str & solution_str and convert back to proto variables 'model' and 'solution'
new_solver = pywraplp.Solver('new_solver', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
new_solver.LoadModelFromProto(model)
new_solver.LoadSolutionFromProto(solution)
# not adding new variables or constraints now
status = new_solver.Solve()
if status = pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
 # goes into an infinite loop
else:
 # no solution
```

However, this solver gets stuck and no output is seen. Although, the same code works with smaller number of 3K variables and 8K constraints. Please advise if this is possible or why is it slow if it has already been solved?

Comment: where does it get stuck? why not just pickle the solver?

Comment: It gets stuck when I call new_solver.Solve(). Pickling the solver gives the error "cannot pickle swigPy objects", my guess is that it is not able to pickle variables, so I'm converting to string.

Comment: Solvers are typically not written in Python but come as C libraries. You can't pickle them.